# Are valence electrons in nonpolar molecules localized/delocalized?

Tags: electrons, physical-chemistry, molecules

Are valence electrons in non-polar molecules localized or delocalized?

I'm quite confused about the whole electron localization and delocalization business.
I'd love a simplified explanation that a high-schooler can understand.

Comment: [chemistry.se] stackexchange?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Chemistry.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by *localised*. Heisenberg's uncertainty principle means there is always a limit to how precisely we can define an electrons position so electrons are always delocalised to some extent. Even in an isolated atom the electron is delocalised across a volume of order an Angstrom radius from the atom.

A simple approach to the electronic structure of molecules is to describe the molecular orbitals as the sum of the individual atomic orbitals (this is known as the [LCAO approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination_of_atomic_orbitals)). So if you take the simplest molecule, hydrogen, you could write:

$$ \Psi_{H_2} \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \psi_{1s}^A + \psi_{1s}^B \right) $$

where $\psi_{1s}^A$ is the $1s$ atomic orbital of hydrogen atom $A$ and likewise for hydrogen atom $B$. In the H$_2$ molecule we no longer have distinct $1s$ atomic orbitals. Instead they merge to form a molecular orbital and the valence electrons are delocalised across the whole molecule.

Now suppose you take the iodine molecule, I$_2$. In the iodine atom the outermost electrons are in the $5p$ orbital, and in the iodine molecule these get delocalised across both atoms in the same way as the $1s$ electrons in hydrogen. However in iodine the $1s$ orbital is deeply buried and is little affected by the presence of the other iodine atom. So in this sense the $1s$ electrons remain localised to a single atom while the $5p$ electrons are delocalised over both atoms.

If you define the *valence* electrons as the ones involved in bonding I suppose you'd have to say they are always *delocalised*, otherwise they wouldn't be able to participate in the bond.

One last point: in chemistry we normally take *delocalised* to mean the electrons are delocalised over lots of atoms, not just the two at either end of a bond. For example we would describe the electrons in [conjugated double bonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugated_system) as delocalised. If we use this meaning of the word then we'd have to conclude some of the valence electrons are delocalised and some aren't. The electrons forming the [sigma bonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_bond) are only spread over two atoms, and only the electrons in [pi bonds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_bond) are *delocalised* over several atoms.

Comment: Does polarity have any effect to the localization of electrons?

Comment: I guess, if a molecule has large dipole moment (polar), it implies that the electrons are concentrated at some part of the molecule. In this sense, the electrons are localized...

Comment: @user32184: In a polar bond the electrons have a greater probability of being on one atom than the other, but the molecular orbital still spreads over both atoms and I think we'd still say the electrons were delocalised over both atoms.